# Where can I get the 'Ubuntu Monospace' font?

Tags: fonts, ubuntu-font-family

Although there is supposed to be a monospace font in the family, the default package doesn't come with it. I tried getting ttf-ubuntu-monospace but there aren't any packages with that name. How/where can I get the monospace font?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Ubuntu Monospace comes preinstalled with Ubuntu 11.10 and it is the default terminal font.

If you want to install it on non-Ubuntu or pre-11.10 machines, download it from [font.ubuntu.com](http://font.ubuntu.com/)!

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but probably the package name is `fonts-ubuntu-title`, so, if missing, that is a package that can be installed

Answer (score 4):

The Ubuntu monospace fonts have been released since this question was asked: http://font.ubuntu.com/

Comment: They also come with Ubuntu 11.10, and in fact Ubuntu Mono 13 is the new default terminal font.

Comment: Ubuntu Mono Regular works fine for me, to display underscores

Answer (score 0):

or you can use [google fonts](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Ubuntu+Mono?preview.text_type=custom)
and get it easily by downloading
the font, getting the link, or
copy the necessary code.